# How do people survive battles in Legend of Korra?

Tags: avatar

In the show, we see tons of battles, most of which use bending. Earthbender can pick up rocks that probably weighty several hundred pounds, but we see people take these with no problem and keep stacking. Firebenders generate intense fire, so how is no one burned even from the non-point blank range? This doesn't add up to me. It could be the infamous rule of cool or something to do with the physiology of the (supposed) humans in the show but I am looking to a different answer.

Comment: I don't think you will find an answer, because this is the case in a lot of animation (especially Japanese anime), and the same logic doesn't apply in live-action shows. The reason a lot of animated shows are so battle-heavy is exactly because of the medium used (animation). It is much easier (and cheaper) to pull off these types of battles in animation as opposed to live-action. Hope this helps!

Comment: @patty2904 Perhaps you could convert your comment into an answer :)